# How to add SCNLookAtConstraint on SCNCamera node in Xcode 9 beta 6 for iOS 11 device

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, ios11

Adding an SCNLookAtConstraint on an SCNCamera node causes a problem when the user double taps the target node in the SCNScene. This problem is new in Xcode 9 beta and doesn't exist when the code is run on iOS 10 device. I filed a bug report with Apple but would appreciate any advice on a work around, besides not adding a constraint. To see the problem, please follow the steps below.

1. Create a new project in Xcode 9 beta 6, selecting the Game application template with Swift for the language and SceneKit for the game technology.
2. Add the following two lines of code in GameViewController.swift after the existing line that retrieves the ship node

   ```
   let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: ship)
   cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
   ```
3. Build and Run the code on a device with iOS 11 beta 8; I ran the code on a 10.5-inch iPad Pro with iOS 11 beta 8.
4. Use one finger to reposition the rotating ship so that the axis of rotation is perpendicular to the screen.
5. double tap the ship with one finger

Expected Results:
The ship should reposition and reorient itself to its original position, with its original axis of rotation and rotation rate.

Observed Results:
The ship spins more and more rapidly, while at the same time getting larger and larger, until it is either barely or no longer in view.